# mysql date query, can find date between two dates, but not date =

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT kpi.id, kpi.event_start, kpi.gwf, aa.first_name, aa.last_name, kpi.visa_type, aa.date_scheduled, kpi.stage
FROM tls_connect_stage_timer kpi
INNER JOIN tls_active_applicants aa ON aa.gwf = kpi.gwf
AND kpi.event_start = '2014-2-19'
 AND aa.first_name = 'Todd'
```

Which does not work, (Works with the kpi.even_start = '2014-2-19' line removed).

And this query:

```
SELECT kpi.id, kpi.event_start, kpi.gwf, aa.first_name, aa.last_name, kpi.visa_type, aa.date_scheduled, kpi.stage
FROM tls_connect_stage_timer kpi
INNER JOIN tls_active_applicants aa ON aa.gwf = kpi.gwf
AND kpi.event_start
BETWEEN '2014-2-18'
AND '2014-2-20'
AND aa.first_name = 'Todd'
```

Which works just fine.  I'm assuming that the problem is the datetime format in the mysql database has seconds included.  How would I go about fixing the first query where I an check a date = a date?

Thanks.

Comment: mysql dates are `yyyy-mm-dd`. You've only got a single digit month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
AND date(kpi.event_start) = '2014-2-19'
```